# Permissions for Network Folder

Tags: networking, permissions

I've looked through for possible answers, and haven't yet found one that fits... 
I have a QNAP ts251 NAS here, and am using keepassx as my password manager.  From the Windows 8 desktop on my laptop I can access my password db (stored in the NAS), and have permission to edit it.  When I access from Ubuntu 16.04 (dual booted on same laptop) I only have read-only access. How can I get full access? I've tried chmod on the Network folders, and also tried to change permissions using the GUI, but it's not happening for me.

Thanks

Comment: What file system is the NAS formatted to?

Comment: Ext4 I think. Qnap ts-251 NAS. I can run Ubuntu in a vm on the NAS via hdmi, and don't have this problem, only when I try to access vial lan

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your issue. Are you Appling 777 with the chmod command?